# How can I compile Assimp with Netbeans in debug mode?

Tags: c++, netbeans, assimp

I am not a C/C++ developer, I tried to google but I couldn't find anything about.

Trying to write a simple java port of Assimp, I modified the `Main.cpp` code runs fine but it doesn't stop at the breakpoint, I guess because I am not compiling in debug mode.

My steps:

- cloned assimp
- from terminal in the directory `cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"`
- opened the project in Netbeans from "existing sources"
- compiled

This is my project Debug Property:

[image]

I don't have any other configuration other than the "Default" one.

How can I solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cmake based projects are configured using the cmake configuration. Instead of switching to debug / release configuration within netbeans - as usual for *"default"* C/C++ Projects - you have to set [**`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) variable accordingly.

Using ***command line***:

- **Debug:** `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`
- **Release:** `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release`

*<sub>You do not need to repeat the other flags like, `-G …`.</sub>*

Alternatively use the ***CMake GUI***.

To get the selectable build configurations you can create them your own (go to ***`Build -> Pre-Build`*** and add calls as above).

---

#### TIP

It's *recommended* to do an ***out-of-source build***.

Comment: Cmake gui didnt work, maybe I did something wrong. From console, no problems, thanks a lot, ollo!

Comment: Last thing, what does *out-of-source build*  mean?

Comment: Out of source means you don't put all build / compile-related files into the source directories. eg. if you have a project in `example/` and source files `example/source/*.cpp`, you put your build files into `example/build`. The Cmake build dir is usually a sub directory of your project.

Comment: Using cmake for out-of-source builds: (1) `mkdir build`, (2) `cd build`, (3) `cmake ..` and finally (4) `make`.